# Determine OneDrive Sync Status From Batch File

Tags: batch-file, dropbox, onedrive

I have a OneDrive account and a Dropbox account. I use a batch file to copy my folders & files to the appropriate places.

At the beginning of the batch file I use SYSINTERNALS PSSUSPEND command to suspend Dropbox. Then when OneDrive is fully synced, I can resume Dropbox using SYSINTERNALS.

I currently use a delay tactic before resuming, but it would be better if I knew exactly when OneDrive was finished.

I could reverse the syncs, but I don't know how to determine the sync status for Dropbox either.

Comment: looking for a better soultion, but in the meantime, for dropbox there is this python script which looks like it might work: http://www.dropboxwiki.com/dropbox-addons/python-script-to-get-file-or-folder-status-in-windows

Answer (score 5):

Late answer, but maybe it helps someone.

One stupid simple solution I just found out myself:
Check out

```
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\OneDrive\logs\Personal\
```

(for Windows, similar user folders in other OSes)

There is a `SyncDiagnostics.log` file.

It gets updated when OneDrive is syncing, checking the status and mapping of online files and when it's done synchronizing. (One little caveat, though: OneDrive won't update the log, when the only file to sync is blocked by a file handle.)

For example, you could check for file modification and then check the variable

```
SyncProgressState:
```

In my experience it shows `0` for done and `255` for syncing.

There are also other interesting variables you can utilize, like `FilesToDownload` and `FilesToUpload` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

download DBStatusc https://sites.google.com/site/macdsite/utilidades/dbstatusc-1
Get the DropBox status in Windows

```
echo WAIT DROPBOX_UP_TO_DATE...
:REPEAT
if exist status.tmp del status.tmp
timeout /t 10
D:\bin\dbstatusc c:\DropBox > status.tmp
findstr /m "Up to Date" status.tmp
if %errorlevel%==1 GOTO REPEAT
...
```