# How to update bigquery database updated by a scheduled script based on sync status of input csv files?

Tags: python, pandas, synchronization, onedrive

### Short Explanation

Some csv files are incoming on a OneDrive Server which is synced onto a machine where a script is running to read them and push them onto BigQuery. And while the script is running fine now, I intend to run it only after all files are synced completely (i.e. available offline) on that machine since last push...

### Long Explanation

So basically I use a local database for sales history of our organization which I want to push to bigquery as well to reflect realtime (lagged) info on dashboards and for other analyses and stuff as a lot of other data besides sales history resides there. Since **database is strictly on-premises and cannot be accessed outside organization’s network** (So literally no way to link to BigQuery!), I have some people there who export day to time sales (sales from start of the day till time of export) info **periodically (1-2hrs) from database and upload to OneDrive**. I got OneDrive on a machine where many other scripts are hosted (Its just convenient!) and I run (python) script for reading all csvs, combine them and push to BigQuery. Often there are duplicates so **it is necessary to read all the files, remove duplicates and then push them to BigQuery** (for which I use:

```
files = [file for file in os.listdir(input_directory) if file.count('-')<=1]
data = [pd.read_excel(input_directory+file) for file in files if file.endswith('.xlsx')]
all_data = pd.concat(data, ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates() 
def upload():
    all_data.to_gbq(project_id = project_id,
                destination_table = table,
                credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
                    'credentials.json'),
                progress_bar = True,
                if_exists = 'replace')
```

What I am trying to do is to is only update bigquery table if there are any new changes when script is run since they don’t always got time to do it.
My current approach is I write the length of dataframe in a file at the end of script as:

```
with open("length.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(len(all_data))
```

and once all files are read in df, I use:

```
if len(all_data) > int(open("length.txt","r").readlines()[0]):
    upload()
```

But doing this needs all files to be read in RAM Reading so many files actually make it a bit congested for other scripts on the machine (RAM-wise). So I do not even want to read them all in RAM as per my current approach.
I tried accessing file attributes as well and tried to build a logic based on date modified as well but as long as a new file is added, it got changed even when file is not fully downloaded on machine. I searched as well to access sync status of files and came across: [Determine OneDrive Sync Status From Batch File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42167353/determine-onedrive-sync-status-from-batch-file) but that did not help. Any help bettering this situation is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

We have similar workflows to this where we load data from files into a database regularly by script. For us, once a file has been processed, we move it to a different directory as part of the python script. This way, we allow the python script to load all data from all files in the directory as it is definitely new data.

If the files are cumulative (contain old data as well as new data) and therefore you only want to load any rows that are new, this is where it gets tricky. You are definitely on the right track, as we use the modified date to ascertain whether the file has changed since we last processed it. in python you can get this from the os library `os.path.getmtime(file_path)`.
This should give you the last date/time the file was changed in any way, for any operating system.

I recommend just moving the files out of your folder containing new files once they are loaded to make it easier for your python script to handle. I do not know much about OneDrive though so i cannot help with that aspect.

Good luck!

Comment: Hey there! I perhaps was unclear before but I am using same `os.path.getmtime(file_path)` method to get its last changed time. But the problem is it is changed once a file is changed even when it is not completely downloaded on the machine